# how do I move my git repositories and keep the same url for cloning?

Tags: git, move, repository, gitolite, git-clone

I currently have repositories in `/home/git/repositories/flt`. I can clone using `git clone git@hostname:flt/root.git`.  `/home/git` is the `$HOME` directory for the git user. I am using gitolite.

I want to move the flt repos to a different path which is not the git home directory.  How can I set it up so that my clone command doesn't change?  I can change git's home directory if that is necessary.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the home of the user `git`, of course, or you make it simple and just link to the new location. Looking at the pathes I assume, that you are using linux ;)

```
ln -s /path/to/new/flt.git /home/git/repositories/flt
```

However, I would just use the new location every time I clone the repository. I don't see a reason (except there are build-script pointing hard-coded to the old location in the wild), why one should use the old path.

Comment: what I am asking is, how does the url work?  how does it know that /home/git/repositories is the parent to flt in the url?

Comment: @user: When you clone via ssh (which is what `git@hostname:path` does), you're sshing in as the user `git`, so non-absolute paths start from the `git` user's home directory. Simple as that.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought.. but the flt directory is under a directory named repositories, it is NOT directly in git's home directory.  So, how does it know to look in repositories?  Is this built in?  Thanks

Comment: Since your repository is being managed by gitolite all the authentication and path resolution is being handled by that application. There's some explanation of what's going on here: http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/gitolite-and-ssh.html